# Is it good practice to make more than 8 ajax call at a time on single submit button event?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am developing one project and it contain 8 dropdowns  and all this dropdowns are optional, for example user can select all 8 dropdown or 5 dropdown or 3 dropdown as per his requirement all are independent, I have written code for all drop down means 8 ajax call on single submit button as of now it is working on my localhost perfectly but if I  place this code in live site  does it make any performance issues to server

Note: All dropdowns are independent so it will call to different methods in controller,for this purpose I can't use form.submit()

my code looks  like this:

```
<select>
  <option>value 1</option>
  <option >value 2</option>
  <option >value 3</option>
  <option >value 4</option>
</select>


<select>
  <option>value 1</option>
  <option >value 2</option>
  <option >value 3</option>
  <option >value 4</option>
</select>

--------------//-------- upto 8 dropdowns


$(".submit").click(function(){

$.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url('controller/method') ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {some_value:some_value },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (response) {
                },   
            });

$.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url('controller/method1') ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {some_value:some_value },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (response) {
                },   
            });
$.ajax({
                url: "<?= base_url('controller/method2') ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {some_value:some_value },
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function (response) {
                },   
            });

and so on 8 ajax calls to different method

});
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but that doesn't mean it's *horrible*, either.

HTTP calls are expensive, and the browser may (probably will) limit how many are allowed to run in parallel to the same origin, often allowing only four (or two on mobile) to run at a time. (Your server may also limit how many it will process concurrently from the same browser, particularly if you're using a session mechanism on the server, in which case it may well process only one at a ttime.) That means the user will be waiting longer than they would be if you were doing a single call or just a couple.

If possible, provide a controller that accepts all eight inputs and do a single ajax call, rather than doing eight ajax calls.

Comment: thanks for your valuable  answer, Actually all dropdowns are calling different methods in different controller and they are independent so it is not possible to call in single request

Comment: @user_1234 - That's what I meant about providing a new controller that accepts all eight inputs (and then presumably passes them on to the eight target controllers). If this is all happening on the same origin, that is, as it appears to be from the URLs in the question.